# Ubuntu Heating Up, Continuos Fan, Hadoop Installation Worries on AMD 64

Tags: power-management, overheating

I have a laptop,

Model: Compaq Presario CQ40, RAM: 2.7 GB RAM, Processor: AMD Athlon X2 Dual Core QL - 64*2, Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS 64 bit and Windows Vista 32 bit (*Factory Installed*)

My laptop gets heated up a lot when I am using Ubuntu and the fan runs continuously (I have **not** chosen "Continuously On" mode for the fan in BIOS settings) .
I am using **Jupiter** with **Power Saving** mode as of now, and the heat has reduced a bit. Also I am using **Ubuntu2D** instead of the default option while logging in.

The temperature is 65+ degrees C when I am not doing much on my machine and gradually increases to 75+ when doing several things at once. I intend to use CDH Hadoop in Pseudo Distributed mode on my machine. I can guess what the temperature will shoot up to then because it uses JVMs. What are the possible things I can do to reduce heat and the fan noise?

Note:

- My laptop model is not listed at [www.linux-laptop.net](http://www.linux-laptop.net/), does that mean my laptop is "Linux-challenged"?
- My main intention is to use Hadoop, I ll be happy if anyone can guide me which [distro is compatible with my machine](https://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_cm_requirements.html#cmig_topic_4_1_unique_1).

Comment: I had once AMD processor and I had the same problem.. I think this is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power management in general is not as good as Linux as it is on Windows in my experience. However, here are some things you can try:

- Install TLP: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html
- Incorporate appropriate changes from vodik powersave: https://github.com/vodik/powersave
- Use `sudo powertop` and make sure all the tunables are "Good"
- Try searching on net for power optimisations for your specific laptop model
- If you have hybrid graphics, enable power saving by disabling the discrete card when not required: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/hybrid_graphics#ATI_Dynamic_Switchable_Graphics

Even after all this, my laptop runs slightly warmer than on Windows, and battery life is not as good. However, it's not that bad, certainly usable. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Note that I am not familiar with AMD hybrid graphics, so I just gave the first link I could find (Arch wiki). If you determine you have hybrid graphics, you might want to try finding something more specific to Ubuntu, e.g. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450.